# AngularJS Display value

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I have in my .html:

```
{{data}}
```

It will display:

```
[ { "images" : [ { "__v" : 0,
          "_id" : "542e57a709d2d60000c93953",
          "name" : "image1",
          "url" : "http://www.syll.com"
        },
        { "__v" : 0,
          "_id" : "543249050fcae2f082ca3e70",
          "name" : "imageOCR1",
          "url_image" : "http://meta-e.aib.uni-linz.ac.at/ocr.gif"
        },
        { "__v" : 0,
          "_id" : "543249050fcae2f082ca3e71",
          "name" : "imageOCR2",
          "url_image" : "http://www.textcreationpartnership.org/xxx.jpg"
        }
      ],
    "itemCount" : 70,
    "pageCount" : 7
  } ]
```

But I would like to display the value in **"pageCount"** so **7**.

How I can do that without ng-repeat?
btw, y controller works fine.

I tried:

```
{{data.pageCount}}
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks!

[EDIT] changed with the righ JSON and formatted.

Comment: The data you are showing is incomplete. If there is a leading "[" there ought to be a trailing "]", too. It seems to me that you should read up on json/javascript literals. Probably for your case {{data[0].pageCount}} will work.

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy/paste. Just edited.

Comment: And please format your JSON so it's readable. Nobody wants to scroll horizontally to find the property you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is all contained within a single-element array. Have you tried the following?

```
{{data[0].pageCount}}
```

Comment: But when I do  <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= {{data[0].pageCount}}" ng-click="getPage(currentPage=currentPage+1)"> it doesn't work

Comment: Really try to work through some tutorials and read code from others. ng-disabled already takes an angular expression, so there is no need for the double curlies: ng-disabled="currentPage >= data[0].pageCount"